# Pass char array on to a function C++

Tags: c++

My goal is to take in a character array and replace specific words such as "class" with the word "video". However, the data in buf array is coming from a web server that has unicode in it, so to my knowledge, I am not allowed to convert the char array into a string because it will mess up much of the data in it (I think).
So, my main question is, how do I pass buf in as an argument to the replaceWords function. Right now I get an error that says,

> error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘char*’ to ‘char [256]’

```
char buf[256];
buf = replaceWords(buf);

char * replaceWords(char* buf) {
    char badWord1[] = "class";
    char * occurrence = strstr(buf, badWord1);
    strncpy(occurrence, "video", 5);
    return buf;
}
```

Comment: If you are using C++, wouldn't [string::replace](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/) be easier to use? Unless you are trying to do this in C and not C++.

Comment: My professor said not to convert my char array to a string because it will mess up some of the data that I eventually send to a web page (null bytes, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void replaceWords(char buf[]) {
    char badWord1[] = "class";
    char * occurrence = strstr(buf, badWord1);
    strncpy(occurrence, "video", 5);

}

int main() {
    char temp[5];
    temp[0] = 'c';
    temp[1] = 'l';
    temp[2] = 'a';
    temp[3] = 's';
    temp[4] = 's';
    replaceWords(temp);
    cout << temp << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It will work as you intend. When you pass `char buf[]` you are passing a reference to the array you want to modify. That way you can modify it in the function and it will be modified everywhere else in the program. There's not need to do additional assignment.

Comment: There are a couple issues with this code. First, this will only work if the substitution string is exactly the same size as the source string. In this case it is, but you should check with OP just to make sure. Second, you are not adding a null termination character, so your `cout` may not work as you expect it to.

Comment: Worked exactly as intended. Thank you

Comment: For my assignment we were only replacing words with other words of the exact same size, so for my case it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by `buf = replaceWords(buf);`. This tries to assign the function return value (`char*`) to an array and that's not valid syntax.

Your code passes the array to the function and the function changes the character string in-place. You don't need the return value from the function. In fact, the function could just be defined as returning `void` and then you can remove the `return` statement.

Note: you should probably add some error checking. What happens if the `badWord1` string is not found and `strstr()` returns NULL?

Comment: Not checking null was another error I had so thank you for pointing it out.